# Identity Server 3: Allow concurrent user sessions with single session logout

Tags: logout, identityserver3, usersession

I am currently having trouble with the identity server 3 and logouts with (single user) concurrent sessions.

**Situation:**
a user is allowed to login (to a mobile app) multiple times with a single account

**Expected behaviour:** 
When the user performs a logout on one device he stays logged in at the other devices.

**Actual behaviour:** 
The user is logged out at each device.

Comment: So the question is: How to achieve that a user can log out on one device, but the other users on other devices keep beeing logged in. And they share the same account.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i would like to achieve